# VBA code to color cell when conditions are met based on 3 columns

Tags: vba

i am working on this code with multiple conditions for a few weeks and it has not been working. I also checked multiple websites for reference to no avail. So basically, my macro is looking at multiple columns. If it shows "RAIL" on Col B and shows either "France" or "Germany" on Col C and col O shows equal to or more than 77 days, that particular cell on Col O will turn red.
Appreciate in advance all the help or recommendations!

Here is my code so far and nothing is being colored when I run it.

'Color code if it shows the ff results
'Col B: RAIL, Col C: either France or Germany, Col O: IF => 77 DAYS

```
Dim rng As Range
Dim rcell As Range
Dim lr As Long
lr = Range("B" & Rows.count).End(xlUp).row
Set rng = Range("B1:B" & lr)

For Each rcell In rng.Cells
    If rcell.Value = "RAIL" Then
        If rcell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "FRANCE" Or rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "GERMANY" Then
            If rcell.Offset(0, 15).Value >= DateAdd("d", 77, Date) Then
                rcell.Offset(0, 13).Interior.ColorIndex = 3
            End If
        End If
    End If

Next rcell
```

Comment: Why not Conditional Formatting?

Comment: YOur issue is that you are testing column D for `France` with `rcell.Offset(0, 2).Value = "FRANCE"` change to `rcell.Offset(0, 1).Value = "FRANCE"`

Comment: And `15` column from B is column Q not column O. `If rcell.Offset(0, 13).Value >= DateAdd("d", 77, Date)`  Remember Offset is the number of cells from the reference

Comment: Thank you so much for the assistance Scott! The meaning or logic behind OFFSET now makes more sense to me! (Need a lot of practice with VBA...) So I changed the code now based on the correct Offset. In my spreadsheet, rows 226 and 227 show RAIL on Col B, FRANCE on Col C and 78 on Col O. Not sure why rows O226 and O227 are not turning red yet...

Comment: What are the values in O, are they dates or numbers?

Comment: Hi Scott, they are numbers. Purely numbers. Thank you!

Comment: Then why are you doing `DateAdd("d", 77, Date)` make it simply `77`

Comment: Thanks Scott for your patience! I am trying to learn VBA by web sources and no formal learning to any programming language so I extremely appreciate your help. I have now changed the code to reflect 77. But it has not colored cells O226 and O227 yet....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved! Thanks to a friendly developer! Apparently, the default compare option in a module is binary, so might have been a spelling issue. So he recommended to set the Compare Text option.

What a learning experience! Thanks guys!

```
 Option Compare Text

 Sub Test()
 Dim B As Range
 For Each B In Range("B1", Range("B" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp))
 With Range("O" & B.Row)
  'No color by default
  .Interior.ColorIndex = xlColorIndexNone

  If B.Value = "RAIL" Then
    Select Case Range("C" & B.Row)
      Case "FRANCE", "GERMANY"
        If .Value >= 77 Then .Interior.ColorIndex = 3
    End Select
  End If
End With
Next
End Sub
```